# Doing correct object referencing in jNode but having invalid data retrieval (using mongoose)

Tags: javascript, database, mongoose, mongoose-schema

I have 2 schemas like this:

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var universitySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    location: String,
    image: String,
    comments: [
        {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "Comment"
        }
    ] 
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("University", universitySchema);
```

and

```
var mongoose = require("mongoose");
var passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");

var commentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    text: String,
    createDate: {type: Date, default: Date.now},
    author: {
        id: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: "User"
        },
        username: String
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("Comment", commentSchema);
```

And it's working fine, I am able to add comments and checked in the database; both the comment and the id found in the university match. But when I try to do something like

```
university.comments[0].createDate
university.comments[0].username
university.comments[0].text
```

or while in a for each loop `comment.username comment.createDate` etc.

It gives me undefined for the user and empty strings for other details I'm trying to get. It was working fine in my other app, I don't know what I messed up here exactly.

Comment: Where is `university` coming from? Is it the result of `.find()` or `.findOne()`?
 If it's `.find()` then `university` is an `Array` itself. It's also a "referenced" schema. Did you call `.populate()`? Because if you did not then there is no object there, and just `ObjectId` values. Also what does "add comments" mean? If you want to do that then you update via the `Comments` model and not `university`. Plenty of existing answers for all of those issues.

Comment: I think you are right its the populate problem goddammit I got bitten by it again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was provided by Neil Lunn in the comments:

> Where is university coming from? Is it the result of .find() or .findOne()? If it's .find() then university is an Array itself. It's also a "referenced" schema. Did you call .populate()? Because if you did not then there is no object there, and just ObjectId values. Also what does "add comments" mean? If you want to do that then you update via the Comments model and not university. Plenty of existing answers for all of those issues.